# Insert icon with g:sortableColumn in grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, gsp

how to insert an icon in grails g:sortableColumn tag

```
<g:sortableColumn property="name" title="${message(code:'project.name.label', default: 'Name')}" /> 
<g:sortableColumn property="age" title="${message(code:'project.age.label', default: 'Age')}" />    
<g:sortableColumn property="phoneNumber" title="${message(code:'project.phoneNumber.label', default: 'Phone Number')}" />
```

i want to insert any one icon along with these table header like this using  bootstrap glyphicon or Font Awesome icon

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with Grails 3.

Place image in `/grails-app/assets/images` for this example were using a file named `sort_both.png`
Then in your gsp...

```
<style type="text/css">
        .headerSort{
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right;
            background-image: url("${assetPath(src: 'sort_both.png')}")
        }
</style>

...

<g:sortableColumn class="headerSort" property="name" title="${message(code:'project.name.label', default: 'Name')}" /> 
...
```